# How do I find out what GDK events are required for a GTK+ signal?

Tags: gtk, glade, gdk

I'm using Glade-3 for my GUI design, but I keep hitting this problem. I don't see anything in the GTK+ documentation mapping signals to events or in Glade-3 (3.4.5). Is there a place in the GTK+ source code to find this information?

Note: It is important in this question to recognize that events and signals are NOT the same thing in GTK.

Example:

I have an eventbox that requires the following events in order to receive the following signals. How do I determine what events are required by a given signal?

```
Events: GDK_ENTER_NOTIFY_MASK | GDK_LEAVE_NOTIFY_MASK | GDK_STRUCTURE_MASK
Signals: leave_notify_event, enter_notify_event
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I think I know what you mean now, I found this table matching up the gtk signals and gdk events. [Here it is](http://developer.gnome.org/doc/GGAD/sec-gdkevent.html#TAB-WIDGETEVENTS).

Comment: That link is now broken, but [this one](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/gui_toolkit_guides/gtk+_gnome_application_development/sec-gdkevent_2.html) works (for now).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that I have interpreted your question correctly you are wanting to connect the signals you specified in the Glade file to the functions in the source code.  How you do this depends if you are using libglade to load the files generate or GtkBuilder, both are similar but I will give samples in C just to be complete.

Using libglade you would do it like so:

```
GladeXml *xml = glade_xml_new(filename, NULL, NULL); // Load the file
glade_xml_signal_autoconnect(xml); // Connect the signals
```

Using GtkBuilder it would be like this:

```
GtkBuilder *xml = gtk_builder_new();
gtk_builder_add_from_file(xml, filename, NULL); // Load the file
gtk_builder_connect_signals(xml, NULL); // Connect the signals
```

When using GtkBuilder the second parameter in signal connect function can be replaced with a pointer to data which will then be passed to the signal handlers.

Going forward I would suggest using GtkBuilder as libglade is on its way to being deprecated.

**Links**

Here are the links to the relevent documentation about the two functions mentioned above

- http://library.gnome.org/devel/libglade/stable/GladeXML.html#glade-xml-signal-autoconnect
- http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkBuilder.html#gtk-builder-connect-signals

Comment: This is a great answer, but it wasn't the answer to my question. I'm going to update the question since it is obviously unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the events with [`gdk_event_handler_set()`](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Events.html#gdk-event-handler-set)

First register your own GDK event handler on startup:

```
gdk_event_handler_set(my_gdk_event_handler, NULL, NULL);
```

... Then use it to print out any useful information, and don't forget to pass the event to GTK+ through `gtk_main_do_event()` like here:

```
void my_gdk_event_handler(GdkEvent *event, gpointer data)
{
    printf("Received GdkEvent of type %d", event->type);

    gtk_main_do_event(event); // Pass event to GTK+
}
```

Comment: I was looking for something like the table given in DoR's answer (which now contains a broken link). However, if I understand correctly, your answer is about how to figure out for yourself what events are triggered from a given signal by inserting a debug event handler?